# Develop Android Xamarian app on Visual Studio 2019 in Windows Server 2019 Virtual Machine running on Windows Server 2016 AMD Server

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, hyper-v

I am an experienced C# ASP .NET Developer trying to develop an Android app in Visual Studio 2019 for the First Time. My Visual Studio is installed in a Virtual Machine running Windows Server 2019. This Virtual Machine is running on an AMD processor based server, Host Operating System is Windows Server 2016.

I created the basic/default Xamarian project in visual studio. When I try to run it I get error that I do not have Intel processor and hardware acceleration is disabled. I can click "Continue". Then it tries to run the Emulator and get error message

> Turn on "Windows Hypervisor Platform" feature to switch to the Native
> Hypervisor and accelerate your emulator.

Since I am already in a VM cannot Turn On Hyper-V. I can, however, click "Run anyway" button. But get another error :- Emulator Error

> Device error: WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value
> ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28'), only 'qemu.'
> properties are supported WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value
> ('emu.uuid=0e874e5d-5d0e-4aa9-8f60-0c351dc95185'), only 'qemu.'
> properties are supported

Google search revels Android Emulator cannot be run on a Hyper-V Virtual Machine. In my development environment/settings, Is there a way to develop Android App in Visual Studio 2019 running in a Hyper-V VM?

Comment: I generally recommend a physical device for development. It just seems to work better and faster. (Although the latest emulator running on tin is vastly superior to what we used to get). If you have access to USB from your VM and can plug in a device to the host and map the USB through, do that. Otherwise  if you have an Android 11 device you could try wifi debugging. https://www.xamarinexpert.it/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-and-say-goodbye-to-cables/

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another VM, such as a VM hosted by VirtualBox, VMware, or Docker (unless using WSL2). You must run the Android emulator [directly on your system hardware](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#extensions)

For information about launching and debugging with the Android emulator, see [Debugging on the Android Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-emulator?tabs=windows)